# REST: query param containing an url

Tags: rest, query-string

How to process query params that will contain values that are urls?

For example if my endpoint is `/endpoint/urls/{urls}` and the query param value urls will contain a url. How should I tell the server that the value of  `{urls}` must be escaped and treated as a string instead of a real url ?

As an example :

> /endpoint/urls/http://www.google.com

Comment: Which technology are you using?

Comment: Java but does it matter ?

Comment: Yes it does matter and a more concrete question would help here, indeed. Did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?

Comment: That's not a query parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the example provided in your question is not a *query parameter*.
It's a *path parameter*.

To send a URL as a query parameter, you must use a key/value pair (`key=value`) and the value must be URL encoded:

```
/endpoint?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

---

To URL encode a value (path or query parameter) in Java, you can use:

```java
String valueUrlEncoded = URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Thank you Cassico. Yes, it's not a query parameter it's a path parameter. The question remains the same. How could I escape the value of a path parameter to be processed as a string if it contains a url?

Comment: @MasterMind Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using Java

Comment: @MasterMind So you can use `URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")` to URL encode the parameter value.

Comment: Thanks ... could you please edit the answer with your last comment so I can validate it ?